# How to do date comparison in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to create the JavaScript function based on date comparison, which means, to compare the Currentday with Currentday+7.

```
function a(value)     
{
  //here how to get current date
  //here how to add 7 days with current date
  return addedvalue;
}


function b(value)
{ 
  var s=a(value);
  //again getting  current date here
   //check this function current date with s.then if its true means show,
  alert('next 7th day is'+s);
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var now = new Date();// gives you the current date.
var sevenDaysFromNow = new Date(); 
sevenDaysFromNow.setDate(now.getDate() + 7); // adds seven days.

function compareDates(d, dd) {
    return d - dd;
};
```

**Date comparison**

If you have two date objects, in this case `now` and `sevenDaysFromNow`, subtracting them `now - sevenDaysFromNow` will return the difference in milliseconds between the two dates. You can convert the difference to a different time unit using simple maths.

```
var ms = sevenDaysFromNow - now;
var hoursDiff = ms / 1000 / 60 / 60;
var daysDif = ms / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/hryDW/3/)

Comment: sevenDaysFromNow.setDate(now.getDate() + 7); if i put like this it shows 1360098

Comment: Am new to script handling.Can u make JSfiddle for this issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29597/discussion-between-v-v-and-alex23)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the current date:

`new Date()`

This will transform it into milliseconds since EPOCH:

`(new Date()).valueOf()`

This will calculate how much time 7 days are:

`7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`

This will transform your integer back to a date:

`new Date(any number of millisecond since EPOCH);`

To complete the example:

```
function a() {
    return new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + (7 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000)); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Date comparison is done using the DateDiff function.
We dont have any comparison function for Date

Comment: this way you are converting date to ms and than comparing, better way is just use the datediff function and check if its result is positive or negative.